# call Soap method using php

Tags: php, xml, soap, curl, wsdl

Hello I am new to use for SOAP But expert in php and curl.

I want to call SOAP URL API method.I have an url where xml is placed like this.If you have an experince in this then Please help me.

```
<definitions name="Vendors" targetNamespace="urn:Vendors">
<types>
    <schema targetNamespace="urn:Vendors">
        <complexType name="userPassword">
            <complexContent>
                <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                    <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
                </restriction>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="userID">
            <complexContent>
                <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                    <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:int[]"/>
            </restriction>
        </complexContent>
        -----------
        -------------
        --------------
        <message name="createNewUserRequest">
            <part name="userPassword" type="xsd:string"/>
        </message>
        <message name="createNewUserResponse">
            <part name="userID" type="xsd:int"/>
        </message>
        -----------
        -------------
        --------------
        <binding name="VendorsBinding" type="tns:VendorsPort">
                <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
                    <operation name="createNewUser">
                        <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/#VendorsController#createNewUser"/>
                        <input>
                            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                        </input>
                        <output>
                            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                        </output>
                    </operation>
                    -----------
                    -------------
                    --------------
        -----------
        -------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) which comes with php since version 5.